# GPO applies as user but not when using a security group

Tags: group-policy

I have this GPO that works fine. I have Authenticated Users in the Delegation Tab with Read permission. Then I have user1 also in the Delegation Tab with Read & Apply permission. GPO (mapping of a printer) is being applied fine.

However, when I remove user1 and replace it with group1 (a global security group and user1 is member) the GPO is not being applied anymore for user1.

I don't get it ...  anyone ?

Thanks in advance.

Marc

Comment: Enable Group Policy verbose logging and check the log file.  `gpresult /h file.html` should also show if the GPO is in scope or not. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-directory-services-team/a-treatise-on-group-policy-troubleshooting-8211-now-with-gpsvc/ba-p/400304

Comment: If  you recently added the user to the group: ensure you Logoff/Logon again to update the group membership of the user on the workstation.